# is python’s fuzzysearch library case-sensitive?

Tags: python, case-sensitive, fuzzy-search, fuzzywuzzy

I can’t find any info about this. Is the [fuzzysearch’s “find_near_matches” function](https://pypi.org/project/fuzzysearch/) case-sensitive by default?

Comment: The [documentation](https://fuzzysearch.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) seems pretty minimal. You may have to try this yourself to see the results.

Comment: Maybe you could try to [contact the authors](https://fuzzysearch.readthedocs.io/en/latest/authors.html) (and ask them to update the documentation)?